# Make an execution timeline on Amazon EMR

Tags: hadoop, emr

I am interested in using the [job_history_summary.py](https://svn.declarativity.net/hadoop-0.19.2/src/examples/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/job_history_summary.py) script to create a Task Timeline of my EMR cluster, similar to this ([picture from Smith College Hadoop Tutorial 1.1](http://cs.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/Hadoop_Tutorial_1.1_--_Generating_Task_Timelines), but apparently from the Yahoo report on the TeraSort experiment.).

[image]

It seems that the Hadoop logs are stored on each node, rather than on the central server. Do I need to manually combine the logs? It also seems that the script doesn't actually produce the graph.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable logging and provide s3 bucket. Logs will be zipped and stored in s3 bucket provided.

[image: AWS EMR enable logging screenshot]